# How to say "can be played"

Tags: word-usage

Es kann mit zwei bis zehn Leute gespielt werden.

That is what I have written off of something I've gathered. This is talking about a game.
I would like it to say "It can be played with 2 to 10 people".

Comment: Almost there. You are missing a "n". Do you find yourself the place?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann If what I wrote was correct (I changed Leute to become Leuten), can you explain how I can use werden with the past participle like this. I took a guess off of what I'd seen on the internet.

Comment: *"Es kann von 2 bis 10 Leuten gespielt werden."* Das ist genau die gleiche Strukturen, wie auf Englisch. Modalverb + Passiv ist eine sehr schöne Konstruktion auf Deutsch. Btw, also Google Translate translates it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As the question got an ammendment in the comments, it now seems to be about the use of *werden* plus past participle, as in:

> Dieses Spiel kann mit 4-6 Leuten gespielt werden.

This is obviously a passive sentence. Here are more of them:

> Der Hund kann auf den Hof gejagt werden.
>
> Die Katze sollte mal gestriegelt werden.
>
> Das Huhn muss gerupft werden, bevor es in den Kochtopf kommt.
>
> Das Ei wird nicht so frisch gegessen, wie es gelegt wird.
>
> Der Tag wird nicht vor dem Abend gelobt.
>
> Das Fahrrad wird in den Schuppen gestellt.
>
> Das Atomwaffenabkommen wird mutwillig in die Tonne getreten.

Does this help?